# React native problem linking SVG Libraries

Tags: react-native, svg, jsx

SO I needed to link react-native-svg

steps I took were:

```
$ npm i --save react-native-svg
$ react-native link react-native-svg
//react-native: command not found

then I did 
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
and again 
$ react-native link react-native-svg
// no output this time
```

now I want to use Text with SVG
I import `import { Svg, G, Line, Rect, Text } from 'react-native-svg'`

however now when I try to use  nothing happened, I just don't see the Text, it does not give me any error but there is no display of my text.

I was wondering, if I missed anything or if there is a way to confirm the that it has been linked.

Comment: Which version react native are you using? If you are using RN 0.60+, there is no need to run the `react-native link` command. Packages are autolinked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used `react-native-svg` before. But I will suspect the library is not linking properly. In normal case, you should be able to know whether a library is successfully linked or otherwise, after you run `react-native link`. If you still couldn't get linking result, I will suggest you go for manual linking.

Answer (score 0):

if You use ios devices and react native version bigger than 0.60, you must use `cd ios && pod install`.
İf not can use `react-native link react-native-svg`